# Error 500 with jsp on GAE/J

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I have a weird error 500 with my JSPs on App Engine.

It's weird because the error happens *only* with the 3 firsts requests of the jsp.

So I browse to the .jsp url, I reload 2-3 times, I have 2-3 errors 500, I hit reload again, it works.

The test.jsp looks like this:

```
<% String s = "hello"; %><h2><% out.println(s); %></h2>
```

The fun thing is that my html files works, the async requests made by js are working too.

I guess I have an made a mistake somewher in the config, but I can't find out.

*edit:*

*I tried to empty the web.xml, the queue.xml and reset appengine-web.xml*

The error log is here on Pastebin: pastebin.com/TDZH4xj3

I also disabled the always on option, and redeployed the app under a new name. Still the same error.

```
2011-04-18 00:10:20.312 /test.jsp 500 3665ms 1820cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.29 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.733.0 Safari/534.29,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)
92.245.143.214 - - [18/Apr/2011:00:10:20 -0700] "GET /test.jsp HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.29 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.733.0 Safari/534.29,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)" "www.planeteimmo.net" ms=3666 cpu_ms=1820 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.050630 loading_request=1



W 2011-04-18 00:10:20.297
Error for /test.jsp
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspInit(test_jsp.java:22)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:261)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9285)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:437)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:573)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)





C 2011-04-18 00:10:20.307
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspInit(test_jsp.java:22)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:238)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:261)
    at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime$2.handleRequest(RuntimePb.java:9285)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication(RpcUtil.java:437)
    at com.google.net.rpc.impl.Server$RpcTask.runInContext(Server.java:573)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:448)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:688)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:326)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:318)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Comment: A 500 is just what App Engine returns to users. What do the logs in the admin console show?

Comment: Here is the full log on Pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/TDZH4xj3

Comment: are you trying to hit the url immediately after deploying on GAE?

Comment: yes, and still happening hours later.

Comment: In the future, please don't paste exception messages in 3rd party hosts. Just include them in your question.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be too long, didn't knew it would scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;

You have servletcontainer specific libaries in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp which is conflicting with the libraries provided by the servletcontainer where the webapp runs. This can happen if you copied for example a `jsp-api.jar` from Apache Tomcat into the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and run the webapp on a servletcontainer of a completely different make/version. In your particular case, one of the libs is of an older version which lacks the in the exception message mentioned method.

Get rid of them all in `/WEB-INF/lib`. They definitely don't belong there. They ought to be supplied by the servletcontainer itself already. If you did this to circumvent compile errors (which is one of the more common reasons starters put them in the wrong place), then it needs to be solved differently.

Comment: That was it, I had some bad .jar's in my /WEB-INF/lib. I never added them on purpose though.
My best guess is that I must have made a mistake when pointing Eclipse app engine tools to an SDK folder.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me as well. I had the gwt-dev.jar in the /WEB-INF/lib dir. It should not be there.